# How would I find the last multiple of three in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is what I've tried so far, can't get the right outputs. I tried going through the array in the reverse direction but got stuck.

```
 public int findMultipleOfThree(int[] arr)
 {
    int multipleOfThree = 0;

    for(int x = arr.length-1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
       if(x % 3 = 0)
       {
           multipleOfThree = x;
       }
    }

    return multipleOfThree;
 }
```

Comment: Please [tag your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) with the appropriate programming language.

Comment: I am not sure about which language is this, but that `x % 3 = 0` seems to be the problem.

Comment: just a typo....  if(x % 3 = 0) should be  if(x % 3 == 0)..... you need to use the equality operator not the assign operator

Answer (score 0):

You defined `x` as the index not the number, so to get the number use `arr[x]` and since you are going in the reverse order, once you find a multiple of 3 you can just return right away.

```
public int findMultipleOfThree(int[] arr)
{
    for(int x = arr.length-1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
       if(arr[x] % 3 == 0)
       {
           return x;
       }
    }

    return -1; // Or whatever the not found variable is
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm supposed to find the index of the last multiple of 3, not the number.

Comment: @SilentShadow no worries, I updated the answer. Just return `x` when `arr[x]` is divisible by 3.

Comment: Does the IF condition work even with `arr[x] % 3 = 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Find the last multiple of three in a primitive java array:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{ 
    public static int findLastMultipleOfThree(int[] arr){ 
        int multipleOfThree = -1; 
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
            if(arr[i]%3 == 0){ 
                multipleOfThree = arr[i]; 
             } 
        } 
        return multipleOfThree; 
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        int[] myarray = {2, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
        System.out.println(findLastMultipleOfThree(myarray));   //prints 9 
    } 
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.